# Relaxation oscillators select resistors

Tags: oscillator

Every circuit diagram of a relaxation oscillator says I have to put a 100 ohm resistor between the capacitor and the voltage source like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpIZf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I think it would be better to use an 1000 ohm resistor instead of a 100 ohm resistor. This would discharge the capacitor at a slower rate and give me a lower frequency.

What do you think?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDo3AS.png)</sup>

Comment: What do _**I**_ think? I think you should simulate it and see if your theory is correct :)

Comment: CircuitLab is also a simulator.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @JRE Does it simulate for anyone? Or do they have to sign up at CircuitLab in order to gain that feature here?

Comment: Jelly, you will need a negative dynamic resistance region for oscillation. The zener doesn't have one. A UJT or PUJT would do, though. You can look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/429550/38098) for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: @jonk:  The CircuitLab simulator works for anyone here.  Just click the "simulate" link under the schematic.

Comment: @JRE I can't test it that way because I actually ***do*** subscribe to them. So of course it works for me. (And it is too much a pain to sign off and then sign back on to test. So I'll just accept answer. I was curious, is all.)

Comment: @jonk I don't subscribe and it demands an e-mail address (and the e-mail is authenticated, there are questions and such like). But if I edit the OP's post I can simulate without supplying an e-mail, but I have to take care to discard the edit. Not ideal.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks. And yes, it sounds like a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your "Zener" K-A is actually something like the E-(B)-C pins of an NPN BJT.

Try this out in real life (I don't think this will simulate).

I think you'll find if you increase the resistor too much, the relaxation oscillator will be very relaxed indeed and will 'stick' after the first breakdown.